# Why does this "satellite antenna at the Laguna Peak Tracking and Injection Facility" look so weird? (two dishes back-to-back)

Tags: identify-this-object, antenna, gps, ground-station

[image: screenshot from the video "1967 Navy Satellite Navigation training film (IBM 7094 data center)" https://youtu.be/aXECyekYPf8]

The video [1967 Navy Satellite Navigation training film (IBM 7094 data center)](https://youtu.be/aXECyekYPf8?t=717) after `11:57` (older version [here](https://youtu.be/AUhVb4p9XLY?t=727)) the narrator says:

> For every pound of satellite in orbit, there are tons of equipment on Earth that make navigation by satellite possible. Let's look at the ground system.
>
> Satellite tracking stations are located in Maine, Minnesota, Hawaii, and California.
>
> Located here at point Mugu California, the (US) Navy Astronautics Group operates the navigation satellite system. The headquarters building contains the operations, communications and computer centers.
>
> Overlooking Point Mugu is one of the system's two injection stations, the other one is in Minnesota.

Here's some screenshots including a closeup of the disk. Behind what looks like a normal dish reflector is what looks to me like another dish of the same size and shape facing backwards, as if they are in a back-to-back configuration.

I don't recall ever seen anything like this, so I'd like to ask:

**Question:** Why does this "satellite antenna at the Laguna Peak Tracking and Injection Facility" look so weird? (two dishes back-to-back)

Here's another view, from China Lake Alumni.org's [Pt. Mugu Photo Gallery.  Last updated 04 August, 2011](http://www.chinalakealumni.org/P-Mugu/P-Mugu.htm) shamelessly enlarged and sharpened, it seems the structure on the back does not look exactly like the dish in the front after all:

[image: from China Lake Alumni.org's "Pt. Mugu Photo Gallery. Last updated 04 August, 2011" http://www.chinalakealumni.org/P-Mugu/P-Mugu.htm]

> A view of a satellite antenna at the Laguna Peak Tracking and Injection Facility, 06 September 1991. Official U.S. Navy photo by PH1 Chuck Mussi.

---

Other screenshots from the video (click for full size):

[image: screenshot from the video "1967 Navy Satellite Navigation training film (IBM 7094 data center)" https://youtu.be/aXECyekYPf8] [image: screenshot from the video "1967 Navy Satellite Navigation training film (IBM 7094 data center)" https://youtu.be/aXECyekYPf8]

Comment: This doesn't look like a second dish to me - more like tilted side walls that shield the space behind the dish, e.g. because electronics are mounted there.

Comment: https://catalog.archives.gov/OpaAPI/media/6349211/content/arcmedia/stillpix/330-cfd/1982/DN-SC-82-02277.jpeg

Comment: @asdfex agreed: "it seems the structure on the back does not look exactly like the dish in the front after all" And that's a beautiful photo! Yes, this station is a "feeder" which I think means it transmits, and there must have been some sensitive electronics like vintage atomic clocks that need to be shielded. And with power radiated from the feed towards the dish there could be spillover around the dish edges, but I'm not sure if this is where shielding would need to be put to protect electronics in a different building. It would suggests the delicate stuff is right under the mount.

Comment: The other "injection station" for the Transit satellite navigation system was at Rosemount, Minnesota, but it appears that there is nothing left of the antenna now. https://clui.org/ludb/site/umore-park

Comment: @OrganicMarble Ah, a wave of melancholiness; I guess it's too late to found the Society for the Preservation of Old Antennas?

Comment: That is really strange. I found this source on the Transit system (https://www.jhuapl.edu/Content/techdigest/pdf/V11-N1-2/11-01-Danchik.pdf). It seems an injection station is just an ordinary ground station. It uplinks commands, including commands to adjust the spacecraft time, but it doesn't sound like any fancy atomic clocks were needed. The skirt (if that's what it's called) seems to be behind the dish, so all it can do is reflect waves diffracting around the edge. I'm guessing this is S-band, 2 GHz, wavelength 15 cm: there wouldn't be much, and it can't shield the feed from ground noise.